# Microcontroller power supply problem

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I'm using an LM7805 regulator in my circuit to supply power for my microcontroller (Attiny 13) and another module.

I have to decrease 5V voltage to 3.3V for the microcontroller so I use two resistors (1k & 2k) to decrease the voltage from 5V to 3.3V
but sometimes the microcontroller does not work well (noise occures in GPIO)
I measure voltage between VCC and GND of the micro , It's about 3.0V
It means I have a 0.3V voltage drop by the microcontroller

I want to know how can I calculate the maximum resistors value (minumum current) to supply the micro ? Of course we have a voltage drop with any value of resistors, but which paramater of the microcontroller tell us how much voltage drop is acceptable for it ? Is there any standard parameter for It ?

Comment: The 1117 [low-dropout regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-dropout_regulator) is often seen supplying 3.3 V from 5 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an LDO regulator rather than a resistive divider. For example, the Microchip [MIC5504-3.3YM5](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC5501-02-03-04-300mA-Single-Output-LDO-in-Small-Packages-DS20006006B.pdf). All you need is one tiny part and two small 1uF ceramic capacitors.

[image]

The resistive divider will cause unstable voltage when the MCU draws different currents, and it wastes power.

This part (and there are many other choices, this is just a particular inexpensive option) will accept up to 5.5V in and supply 3.3V out even if the output current is relatively large.

Inspired by @ChrisStratton, here is one way to think of how a linear LDO works (with apologies to Winfield Hill et al.)

[image]

"Regulator man" adjusts the pot to maintain the output voltage at 3.3V. If the load is heavy the pot gets turned to a low resistance, if there is little load then the pot gets turned to a very high resistance. All Regulator Man can do is turn the pot to almost zero resistance so the output voltage can never quite reach the input voltage. Iq is just a bit of current the regulator needs to work.

Comment: Effectively a linear regulator is the version of a resistive divider that *actually works* for a variable load, because it's a self-varying upper half of a resistive divider that adjusts its resistance to produce the desired output voltage under the actual load conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use resistors to supply the power to the micro - the supply current varies too much. This, in turn, will cause excessive variation of the supply voltage.

Why not power everything off 5V or 3.3V? The ATtiny13 can use either.

If you cannot do that then it is better to provide a regulated supply for the ATTiny.

Comment: No , my attiny does not work with 5V I don't know why, I'm trying to make my board as cheap and simple as possible so I want to use just one regulator , I can remove the noise by decreasing resistors value , but I want to know is there an standard calcution for it ?

Comment: @MohamadAliZeraatkar - it should be able to work from 1.8-5.5V. What happens on 5V that tells you it is not working?

Comment: Yes I read this voltage range in the datasheet but my micro doesn't work with lower than 2.5V and more than 4V (in my code it should set a pin to high at start , but it doesnt happen)

Comment: The lower limit is probably the brown-out setting. There isn't any particular setting to stop it working at a higher voltage though.

Comment: @MohamadAliZeraatkar - you need to work out why it doesn't work at 5V rather than designing around it. The micro should work at 5V. I use them voltages from 1.8 to 5V with no problem. Just be careful about your brownout settings .

Comment: Yes I found the problem, its not from the micro, its from the other module (RF433mhz receicver) that connected to regulator and when micro is connected directly to regulator (in parallel with receiver module) the module doesn't work well ,I measure the output voltage of regulator , it was 5V so it's not the voltage drop that cause problem ,seems the micro makes a noise on it when directly connected to regulator